# Disable touchmove for element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an app, and for iOS a certain component is scrollable. I don't need to check why is this happening, I'd like to disable the touchmove on that element for good.

I've tried something like:

```
$(element).bind('touchmove', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

But this does not stop the touch scrolling. How can I disable the touchmove?

Comment: If all you need is to remove the scroll i think you can just use "overflow: hidden" in your css

Comment: have you verified the element has a `touchmove` listener bound to it? if so, and you want to remove it, you could try jquery's `off` function: http://api.jquery.com/off/